# Spring Boot Mapping a JSON to set a refereced object in the new that is being created

Tags: json, spring-boot, object, request, bind

How to bind my new object user with an role object in my spring boot application when I receive an request post with a json/application that has all data for the new user?
What is the best approach (inform the role in the json)? If yes, how must be the json concerned the role information?

I will try to explain myself. First, I am sorry, I am not a native English speaker.

I want to create a new object user mapping the json received from a HTTP request post. The problem is that I have an internal object from my model named role. Roles are always either a common or an admin. Then I want to reference an already instantiated role object.

**So, I want to know how to indicate the role from my user.** You should consider that the model can not be modified because some internal team restriction. I don't know if the correct restful approach is send the role information in the json. How would you do this task?

My code

Class Controller

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/users", produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<EntityUser> create(@Validated @RequestBody EntityUser user)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.add(user), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

The Service class

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    public EntityUser add(EntityUser user)
    {
        if (userRepository.findByName(user.getName()) == null)          
            return userRepository.save(user);
        return null;
    }
}
```

My plain object EntityUser (the json is mapped to it).

```
@Entity
public class EntityUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="user_sequence")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
//  @NotNull
    private EntityRole role;

...

}
```

and finally my EntityRole class

```
@Entity
public class EntityRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="role_sequence")
    private long id;    

    @NotNull
    private String label;

    @NotNull
    private String permission; 
  ...
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you accept a UserCreateRequest which includes user info and role info as RequestBody in the controller? Thus you can create user with role.